# Wireshark Displayed Packets

Tags: wireshark, pyshark

I am a Wireshark learner and currently I am using Tshark to sniff my network packages. Currently my local IP is 192.168.0.114 and my collegue is 192.168.0.102.
However when I start capturing packets, I receive some packets with source IP 192.168.0.102 and destination IP 192.168.0.255. I am not the sender nor the receiverWhy am I seeing those packets? Here is my code just in case>

```
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='eth0')
capture.sniff(timeout=50)
capture
```

Answer (score 2):

192.168.0.255 seems to by the **broadcast IP address** : 192.168.0.102 send this message to all other hosts on the network, your computer is receiving it as a member of this subnet.
The mask is probably 255.255.255.0 :)